# How do I use chef to download a file from AWS S3 and save this to a particular directory using chef?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chef-infra

Trying to use chef to download a file from a private AWS S3 bucket and save this in a local directory using chef. Any tips/tricks?

Comment: please share what you have tried so far and any issues you have come across

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a web directory listing with the below script and use [remote_file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) resource to download files from amazon S3

https://aws.amazon.com/code/amazon-s3-bucket-listing/

Answer (score 0):

You would generally use the `s3_file` resource from the cookbook of the same name.